# Are scalar multiplication and the tensor product related?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let's say we have two $R$ modules, $V$ and $W$, and $R$-module homomorphisms: $$S: V \to R, \quad T: W \to R. $$
Then we can define the tensor product $S \otimes T$ to be: $$(S \otimes T)(v \otimes w):=S(v)\cdot T(w). $$

> **1.** Is this definition implicitly using the fact that $R \otimes R \cong R$?

Specifically: $$S(v) \otimes T(w) = [S(v)\cdot 1]\otimes[T(w)\cdot 1] = [S(v)\cdot T(w) \cdot 1] \otimes 1 = [S(v)\cdot T(w)]\otimes 1 \cong S(v) \cdot T(w)? $$

> **2.** Is $R \otimes R \cong R$ simply because multiplication, $\cdot : R \times R \to R$, is bilinear? And the reason why multiplication is bilinear is because of the distributive property?

Specifically, using the [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property) of the tensor product: $$\begin{array}{rcl} R \times R & \overset{\varphi}{\to} & R \otimes R \\ \cdot & \searrow & \downarrow \bar{h} \\ \, & \, & R \end{array}$$ we have that $\bar{h}\circ \varphi = \cdot$, by the universal property (I think, or at least from the construction of $R \otimes R$ as a quotient of a free vector space) $\bar{h}$ has to be injective, and since both $\varphi$ and $\cdot$ are surjective, and $\bar{h} \circ \varphi = \cdot$, $\bar{h}$ also needs to be surjective, and thus is bijective and thus an $R$-module isomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the first question is no. The definition of $S\otimes T$ only depends on the fact that $\varphi: V\times W \rightarrow R, (v,w)\mapsto S(v)\cdot T(w)$ is bilinear.

As for the second question, multiplication indeed induces an isomorphism $R\otimes R\cong R$. The distributive property implies bilinearity. The surjectivity follows from the fact that $x\otimes 1$ is mapped to $x$ for any $x\in R$. The injectivity follows from the fact that we can write any element in $R\otimes R$ as $\sum_i^n x_i\otimes y_i=(\sum_i^n x_iy_i)\otimes 1$.

Comment: So could we also define the tensor product of $S$ and $T$ using any bilinear map in place of scalar multiplication? I want to make sure I understand your answer to the first part.

Comment: @William Yes, if $\psi :R\times R\rightarrow R$ is any bilinear map, then $\varphi:V\times W\rightarrow R,(v,w)\mapsto \psi(S(v), T(w))$ induces a linear map $V\otimes W\rightarrow R$. However, as far as I know, this would not be denoted by $S\otimes T$ if $\psi$ is not the multiplication map.

Comment: Oh OK, for some reason I thought you meant any bilinear map, mapping into any arbitrary space, i.e. $\psi : R \times R \to X$, bilinear -- this makes more sense, since $R \simeq R \otimes R$, the homomorphism $R \otimes R \to R$ induced by _any_ bilinear map $\psi: R \times R \to R$ is an isomorphism, i.e. $\psi$ as scalar multiplication is only _one_ possible choice.

Comment: @William This is not correct. Not every bilinear map $\psi:R\times R\rightarrow R$ induces an isomorphism $R\otimes R\cong R$.

Comment: @Wiliam Maybe I misinterpreted your original question. In general, if $S:V\rightarrow M, T:W\rightarrow N$ are $R$-linear maps of $R$-modules, then one obtains an $R$-linear map $S\otimes T:V\otimes W\rightarrow M\otimes N$ such that $(S\otimes T)(v\otimes w)=S(v)\otimes T(w)$. This specializes to the case in your question: $M=N=R$ after using the fact that $R\otimes R\cong R$ under the map induced by multiplication.